# C# AssignedSchedule Task Sequence SDK SCCM

Tags: c#, sdk, sccm

I am using the SCCM SDK and creating a deploy using the C# code below:

```
            const Int32 OVERRIED_SERVICE_WINDOWS = 0x00100020;
            const Int32 ENABLE_PRESENT = 0x01000000;
            const Int32 REMOTE_FLAG = 0x00041040;

            try
            {
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

                IResultObject novoDeploy = connection.CreateInstance("SMS_Advertisement");

                  novoDeploy["CollectionID"].StringValue = collectionID;
                  novoDeploy["PackageID"].StringValue = pacote;
                  novoDeploy["ProgramName"].StringValue = nomePrograma;
                  novoDeploy["AdvertisementName"].StringValue = "Deploy Teste SDK";
                  novoDeploy["Comment"].StringValue = "Deploy realizado via SDK";
                  novoDeploy["AdvertFlags"].IntegerValue = novoDeploy["AdvertFlags"].IntegerValue | OVERRIED_SERVICE_WINDOWS;
                  novoDeploy["DeviceFlags"].IntegerValue = 0;//novoDeploy["DeviceFlags"].IntegerValue | ENABLE_PRESENT;
                  novoDeploy["RemoteClientFlags"].IntegerValue = novoDeploy["RemoteClientFlags"].IntegerValue | REMOTE_FLAG;
                  novoDeploy["AssignedScheduleEnabled"].BooleanValue = true;
                  novoDeploy["OfferType"].IntegerValue = 0;
                  novoDeploy["PresentTimeEnabled"].BooleanValue = true;
                  novoDeploy["PresentTime"].DateTimeValue = now;
                  novoDeploy["Priority"].IntegerValue = 1;
                  novoDeploy["TimeFlags"].IntegerValue = novoDeploy["TimeFlags"].IntegerValue | ENABLE_PRESENT;

                  List<IResultObject> collectionSchedule = novoDeploy.GetArrayItems("AssignedSchedule");
                  IResultObject collectionVariable = 
 connection.CreateEmbeddedObjectInstance("SMS_ST_NonRecurring");
                  collectionVariable["StartTime"].DateTimeValue = now;
                  collectionSchedule.Add(collectionVariable);
                  novoDeploy.SetArrayItems("AssignedSchedule", collectionSchedule);

                  novoDeploy.Put();
```

I need to deploy with a scheduled date, but I'm getting errors.
Do you know what settings I should leave in the Advert Flags fields to perform this scheduled deploy?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @Syberdoor, can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you try to write to the TimeFlags property here:

```
novoDeploy["TimeFlags"].IntegerValue = novoDeploy["TimeFlags"].IntegerValue | ENABLE_PRESENT;
```

which according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/develop/reference/core/servers/configure/sms_advertisement-server-wmi-class#timeflags) is a ReadOnly flag.
Regarding your use case it says:

> Reserved for internal use. Flags that duplicate the information in the
> time-related properties. Possible values are listed below. For
> example, ENABLE_PRESENT is set when PresentTimeEnabled equals true.

So as you already set PresentTimeEnabled you should be fine with just leaving out that line.